# Stuck converting Javascript function to VB.Net

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I need help converting the following JS-function to vb.net please:

```
function testjs(s) {
    var dict = {};
    var data = (s + "").split("");
    var currChar = data[0];
    var oldPhrase = currChar;
    var out = [currChar];
    var code = 256;
    var phrase;
    for (var i=1; i<data.length; i++) {
        var currCode = data[i].charCodeAt(0);
        if (currCode < 256) {
            phrase = data[i];
        }
        else {
           phrase = dict[currCode] ? dict[currCode] : (oldPhrase + currChar);
        }
        out.push(phrase);
        currChar = phrase.charAt(0);
        dict[code] = oldPhrase + currChar;
        code++;
        oldPhrase = phrase;
    }
    return out.join("");
}
```

What my code looks like at the moment:

```
Private Function questionmarkop(ByVal ph As String, ByVal dictatcurr As String, ByVal ophoc As String) As String
    Return If(ph = dictatcurr, dictatcurr, ophoc)
End Function
```

```
Private Function testvb(ByVal s As String) As String
        Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
        Dim data As Char() = s.ToCharArray
        Dim currchar As Char = data(0)
        Dim oldphrase As String = currchar
        Dim out As String() = {currchar}
        Dim code As Integer = 256
        Dim phrase As String = ""
        Dim ret As String = ""
        For i As Integer = 1 To data.Length - 1
            Dim currcode As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(data(i))
            If currcode < 256 Then
                phrase = data(i)
            Else
                phrase = questionmarkop(phrase, dict(currcode), (oldphrase + currchar))
            End If
            ReDim Preserve out(out.Length)
            out(out.Length - 1) = phrase
            currchar = phrase(0)
            dict.Item(code) = oldphrase + currchar
            code += 1
            oldphrase = phrase
        Next
        For Each str As String In out
            ret = ret + str
        Next
        Return ret
    End Function
```

When inputting the following string s: `thisĂaveryshorttestđringtogiĆanexamplefČđackoĆrflow`

The function should return: `thisisaveryshortteststringtogiveanexampleforstackoverflow`

The js function does exactly that, my vb function does not sadly.
The first time (or basically everytime) the if statement is not true, the next character will be wrong. So i figure there is something wrong with the line `phrase = questionmarkop(phrase, dict(currcode), (oldphrase + currchar))`.
With the test string i provided everything works until `this`, after that i have the first false char.
Can someone help me figure out what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the two routines to see where their behavior differs?

Comment: @Craig Yes indeed, happens at the following parts.
JS: `phrase = dict[currCode] ? dict[currCode] : (oldPhrase + currChar);`
VB: `phrase = questionmarkop(phrase, dict(currcode), (oldphrase + currchar))`

Comment: I think the equivalent of this: `dict[currCode] ? dict[currCode] : (oldPhrase + currChar)` will be something like this: `If(dict.ContainsKey(currCode), dict(currCode), oldPhrase & currChar)`.

Comment: If that ternary is what you're stumbling on, I would highly recommend to edit your question to call attention to it.  The more focused your question is, the more likely you are to get good answers (and the less likely it is to be closed for insufficient focus/effort).

Comment: @craig thank you for you anwers. I tried implementing your code snipped,  but i have no idea how that would work. I just get the error `Value of type cannot be converted to 'Boolean'.`

Comment: Your error doesn't make any sense.  `dict.ContainsKey(currCode)` should return boolean which is expected as the first operand to the ternary operator, and `dict(currCode)` and `oldPhrase & currChar` both should be `String`.

Comment: @Craig well i am not used to working with ternary operators, i figured it out. And you would not believe it you actually solved my problem! I can't thank you enough, i was sitting at this for 9 hours at least..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on discussion in the comments, it seems like the issue was producing a VB translation for this line:

```js
phrase = dict[currCode] ? dict[currCode] : (oldPhrase + currChar);
```

I have only passing familiarity with Javascript, but I believe the key here is that `dict[currCode]` will return a type of null or missing value if there is not already an entry in the dictionary with key `currCode`.  The .NET dictionary has facilities that will let you get the same effect, though the exact implementation is a little different.

The direct VB equivalent to this ternary and assignment is (I believe):

```vb
phrase = If(dict.ContainsKey(currCode), dict(currCode), oldPhrase & currChar)
```

You can eliminate a key lookup on the dictionary by using `Dictionary.TryGetValue`:

```vb
If Not dict.TryGetValue(currCode, phrase) Then
    phrase = oldPhrase & currChar
End If
```

I doubt the code is performance-sensitive enough to care about the difference, so I would recommend to use the alternative that you find more clear to read.